# Change color in a stack bar plot with more than 11 colours

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm a beginner using R and I'm creating a ggplot-geom_bar (stack) to demonstrate diferences in percentage of compounds. However I have more than 11 colours and I cannot change the fill colours

I'm using the following code:

```
vermelha_bio_stack <- ggplot() +
  geom_bar(data=vermelha_pom, 
           aes(y=values, x=month,fill= factor(compunds)), 
           stat="identity") + 
  xlab("") + 
  ylab("Percentages") + 
  scale_fill_discrete(name = "Compounds") +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,101), expand=c(0,0)) +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(
    text=element_text(family = "sans"),
    axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),
    axis.line.x.bottom = element_line (color = "black"),
    axis.line.y.left = element_line(color = "black"), 
    panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white")) + 
  ggtitle("Lagoa Vermelha")  +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(color="black", size=14, face="bold", hjust = 0.5))+ 
  coord_flip()
```

and I got the following plot

[image]

but I want colours like the following image:

[image]

Comment: Why can you not change the fill colors? You can always use `scale_fill_manual` and supply your desired colors via the `values` argument if scales like the ones from ColorBrewer don't provide enough values or you can extend color pallets from ColorBrewer with`colorRampPalette`.

Comment: It worked very well, thanks!!